# Remove the first nine characters and the last two from a file

Tags: sed

I need to turn this `hello123456789`into `567` using `sed` to remove the first nine characters and the last two.

I have looked for a command just cant find one i have tried a few languages to execute a function to do it but had no luck.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does it have to be sed, or are other solutions also possible (e.g. shell methods)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/^.........\(.*\)..$/\1/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/^.\{9\}\(.*\)..$/\1/' file
```

or, using the non-standard but commonly implemented `-E` option to enable the use of extended regular expressions,

```
sed -E 's/^.{9}(.*)..$/\1/' file
```

All of these first matches nine characters at the start of the line, then any number of  characters in the middle of the line (these are captured), and finally two characters at the end.  Anchoring with `^` and `$` is actually not needed here as the middle section of the expression forces the first and last bit of the expression to match at the start and end of the line anyway. The whole line is replaced by the captured characters in the middle, however many they may be.

Another approach with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/.\{9\}//' -e 's/..$//' file
```

This first expression removes the first nine characters by means of substituting them with nothing, and the second expression removes the last two characters in a similar manner.  The second expression needs the anchoring at the end of the line with `$`, but the first expression does not need to be anchored as it matches from the start of the line by default.

---

If the string is in a shell variable `var`, then using these two standard variable substitutions would first remove the first nine, then the last two characters of the string (`?` matches any character when used in a shell globbing pattern):

```bsh
var=${var#?????????}
var=${var%??}
```

This mimics the last variation with `sed` above in that it matches and removes certain number of characters at the start and end of the string without bothering about the middle section of the string at all.

Testing this:

```
$ var=hello123456789
$ var=${var#?????????}
$ var=${var%??}
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
567
```

Answer (score 5):

Using bash parameter expansion:

```
string=hello123456789
echo ${string:9:-2}
567
```

Answer (score 2):

To just not missing the `awk` solution:

```
awk -v s=9 -v e=2 '{ print substr($0, s+1, length()-s-e ) }' infile
```

see [substr(string, startPos, length)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of your file are

```
hello123456789
```

You can do:

```
sed 's/.\{9\}\(.\{3\}\).*/\1/' <your_file
```

The command works by matching:

- 9 characters of any type: `.\{9\}`
- The stuff in between the `\(` and `\)` is remembered and matches 3
  characters of any type `.\{3\}`
- Then replace with the remembered content `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Another (`bash`) fancy way :

```bsh
str="hello123456789"
[[ "$str" =~ ^.{9}(.*).{2}$ ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```